Are logic and mathematics the only fields in which certainty (proof) can be obtained?
Layman in philosophy question here!
Albert Einstein once said "No number of experiments can prove me right; a single experiment can prove me wrong." (according to David Halliday, ‎Robert Resnick and ‎Jearl Walker (1993) Fundamentals of Physics, Volume 2, page. 627) So, it seems Einstein believed that his theories could never be proved.
I am a very skeptical person, with a phobia of uncertainty and changes. I like things that I know for sure are true and will remain true. Are logic and mathematics the only fields where what we say can be proved, and therefore be true without doubts? How do we know that logic itself is not flawed?

But we should have doubts. We are not better at doing logical calculations than a computer is. Sometimes, a computer will make a calculation error. Humans make a lot more calculation errors than computers do.

A don't believe any truth that does not have a logical argument to confirm it to be the truth that truth must be based upon claims of  statements that convince you of those  statements!! Can you prove me wrong?

@causative shame on you a human is just as capable as a computer in performing calculations. It's not hard to add a multiple of one thing to a multiple of another.Jesus

What is your standard of certainty? Because not even logic and mathematics may be able to deliver the certainty you like. "In practice, and in fact, mathematics is not exempt from that liability to error that affects everything that man does. Strictly speaking, it is not certain that twice two is four. If on an average in every thousand figures obtained by
addition by the average man there be one error, and if a thousand million men have each added 2 to 2 ten thousand times, there is still a possibility that they have all committed the same error of addition every time." C. S. Peirce.

It is not even just a question of making errors. Proofs themselves proceed from assumptions about how logics work, so why should you suppose they produce certainty?

Mathematics and logic are the "paradigm" for certainty, in the sense that it is the "best approximation" that humans achieved.

Most modern Mathematics and Logic is grounded in axioms, which are simply assumed.  So, while one gets the satisfaction of a seemingly iron-clad proof structure, the proofs are actually always for statements of the form "If {A} then X", where X is whatever you wanted to prove, and {A} is your axiom set.  So a proof of "0+1=1" is only stated as such for brevity.  It's actually a proof that "If the axioms hold, then 0+1=1"  Incidentally, "0+1=1" basically IS an axiom in Peano arithmetic, so the rigorous Mathematical/Logical proof for this statement is "well, we just assumed it was true"

We just need to pick the right axioms.

"I am a very skeptical person, with a phobia of uncertainty and changes."  Unless you have a mental illness that prevents you from going (relatively) new places and doing (relatively) new places, you go places where you aren't certain that the roof won't collapse, that you won't slip and fall, the chain won't collapse, etc.

Heck, you can't be certain that the chair (or bed) that you're on won't suddenly collapse, or that a hole in the ground won't open up right under your feet.  And yet you sit on that chair anyway, lay on the bed, and walk around.


A statement about a single event like “today it rains at Manhattan”
can easily be confirmed or refuted in daily life by inspection.
The epistemic problems are about general statements. The textbook
example “All adult swans are white” has been refuted after discovering
that indeed there some non-white swans in Australia. Scientific
theories provide general statements. According to the philosopher
Karl Popper they cannot be proved. Instead they are hypotheses which
can be confirmed or refuted. Refutation is possible by a single
counter-example, that’s what Einstein means.
In mathematics and logic one has axiomatized theories
like number theory, group theory, topology, … . Here one can prove
that general statements derive from the axioms of the theory. But
the axioms cannot be proved. Hence the proof of general statements
is always a proof relative to the axioms.

There is no ultimate justification for general statements. We have either confirmed hypotheses in science or relative proofs in axiomatized theories.

Ooooo --- "it rains in Manhattan" is easy!???? What's Manhattan, the borough? The island? The town in Kansas!?? What's rain? One drop? Does it have to rain anywhere (very hard to disprove!!) or everywhere (equally hard to prove!!)? What counts as proof here? A single observation? By whom? Only meteorologists? Lay people? What if they are confused or something dripped on them? -- Natural language and reality are messy.

@Peter-ReinstateMonica You point out not the difficulty to determine whether “it rains in Manhattan” is a true statement. You emphasize the difficulty to define(!) its two terms, which is necessary to give the statement a precise meaning.

I also point out the near impossibility to fully prove either one of the two possible meanings (anywhere or everywhere are equally hard), and the problem with human falsification or verification.

Wow, nice comments! What if I'm sleeping/dreaming? Or having hallucinations/delusions? Philosophy is very interesting! Or what if someone is tricking me into believing it's raining, with speakers (after having recorded the sound of raining) for example?

You say:

Albert Einstein once said "No number of experiments can prove me right; a single experiment can prove me wrong." (according to David Halliday, ‎Robert Resnick and ‎Jearl Walker (1993) Fundamentals of Physics, Volume 2, page. 627) So, it seems Einstein believed that his theories could never be proved.

This is related to the debate that emerged among logical positivists and their critics about verificationism, refutations, and confirmationism. The gist is that induction is a tricky beast as Hume recognized and noted; there's a problem with induction. It doesn't grant certainty in the same way deductive methods do. A classic historical example of the potential failure of inductive reason are black swans. All swans in Europe for millennia had been white. So, it was quite reasonable to say all swans are white. Yet, when Europeans showed up Down Under, they found black swans. Thousands of years of observations were undone in a single encounter, which is the essence of Einstein's quotation.
You ask:

Are logic and mathematics the only fields where what we say can be proved, and therefore be true without doubts? How do we know that logic itself is not flawed?

The short answer is that formal systems like mathematical logic that obey formal deduction are very certain, but sometimes a logic doesn't do a good job of modeling natural language or the physical world. In a prior century, there was a great faith in the power of deduction and educated persons spoke of the Laws of Thought. Today such views and systems are known as classical logic and have been expanded on by non-classical logics. Today, a growing number of logicians subscribe to logical pluralism. According to WP:

Logical pluralism is the philosophical view that there is more than one correct logic. It stands in contrast to logical monism which argues that there is a single unique logic. There are different standards both for what counts as a logic and what exactly it means for a logic to be "correct", however, most debates about logical pluralism defined logic as a theory of validity. In other words, logic is the study of what constitutes a valid inference. Following from this definition, "correctness" has been defined in terms of whether or not a logic offers the correct form of valid inference. Logical pluralism holds that multiple different types of valid inference (i.e., at least two different consequence relations) can be correct.

Lastly, you ask:

Are logic and mathematics the only fields in which certainty (proof) can be obtained?

The answer is generally no, because certainty of belief can come in many ways. Fideism, for instance, holds that logic is actually inferior to faith for being certain about particular types of truth. In the philosophy of law, there are certain legal standards of evidence and a burden of proof that when met can confer certainty on conclusions. Lastly, besides rational methods like deduction, classical empiricism has brought notions of empirical evidence to the table in critical thinking. Evolution, for instance, is a scientific theory that is held in high regard by scientists precisely because it integrates so many theories and has been so thoroughly tested since Darwin proposed it.
Thus, certainty in the broader picture comes in many shades of gray, and modern logicians recognize that deduction, induction, and abduction are all distinct methods that confer different degrees of certainty to inference. Modern epistemologists are often inclined to see nothing as absolutely certain in the spirit of fallibilism (IEP). And reliabilist epistemology (SEP) holds justification is not found necessarily in evidence, but in processes, among others, that build psychological history. After all, confidence often has nothing to do with proof whatsoever when it stems from psychological overconfidence.

Yes, I agree with this response! The answer to the question is no, because logic and mathematics are caught up in the web of uncertainty.  Logic is the thread that holds the web together, but that which holds is also being held!

"Trust, but verify."

I love the idea that you can only be real certain about things you believe in. Proven every day anecdotally when talking to a true believer ...


"No number of experiments can prove me right; a single experiment can prove me wrong."

This is simply a more personalized formulation of the Scientific Method, no more no less.
Science tries to explain something that we observe in reality; this, in a nutshell is why they use (first and foremost) the concept of Falsifiability, which in turn basically means that reality is always "correct". No matter how great or elegant your theory is – if reality, as demonstrated by even a single experiment, is of a different opinion, then reality wins. There are no proofs in science, everything is just a theorem, and everything can be disproven at any point in time.
In philosophy proper and, by extension, maths, this is not the case, or at least not as fundamentally. These are buildings built on free-floating ideas, concepts, axioms, definitions, opinions, which have no required relationship to physical reality. For example, you will not ever find an experiment that shows you that the Categorical Imperative is "wrong" (nor one that shows that it is "right"). You can of course try to come up with a thought building (probably involving counting the overall happiness of all entities in the universe and such things) trying to "prove" the imperative in some kind of ruleset, but nothing of this will ever be any more "real" than any other ruleset you could come up with.
You can see this by witnessing that for every conceivable philosophical topic, you always find many different viewpoints. Often they differ slightly, but also often they say the complete opposite of each other. For example, you will find philosophical arguments for and against Free Will. Nobdoy has come up with a way to "prove" once and for all whether Free Will exists, and I find it likely that it never will happen. At the same time you will find many people that hold that "clearly" their own side is the only correct one. They still are not able to convince the people on the other side, and likely never will.
Maths is kind of a special case as it also exists completely in its own space, but of course due to the developments in the early 20th century (c/f the Foundation of Mathematics and especially the chapter about the foundational crisis) it is now based on an extremely specific and rigorous set of (very few, considering) axioms and rules. For the most part, anything you encounter in maths can or cannot be reduced to said axioms, and then you know whether it's "certain". This only requires that you do, indeed, accept a particular set of axioms, which is not always clear (e.g. Constructivists deny that concepts like infinity should be part of maths), and then the same uncertainties like in other areas of philosophy abound. But at the very least there is an overwhelming majority in "standard" maths.

phobia of uncertainty and changes

This indicates a very rough time ahead. There is nothing more certain than change; everything you know will end; everybody you know will die; including yourself. And all of that can happen in any instant in time. The planet will near certainly not exist anymore at some point, the sun will go out, and so on and forth. Indeed, your body is changing daily more than you could ever imagine; cells die all the time and get replaced.

I know for sure are true and will remain true

Difficult.

Are logic and mathematics the only fields where what we say can be proved, and therefore be true without doubts?

No, logic and maths are not sure and proven, and could at any time "explode". We have witnessed that with the Foundational Crisis at the end of the 19th century. Even if mathematicians are relatively happy these days, nobody can be sure that such a crisis does not appear again at some point in time.

How do we know that logic itself is not flawed?

But logic is flawed. First of all, formal logic can become complicated quickly, so it is unwieldy in everyday life. Search for the word "reject" in Philosophy of Logic and you will find a good amount of topics where different philosophical streams differ in their approaches of opinion. There is not only "one" logic.
Worse, even if you are the most logical person around (or especially then), chances are that you are surrounded by a much larger share of people who do not function in a recognizably logical manner - this makes it very frustrating to use logic to solve e.g. interpersonal or "larger" problems. For example, try to use logic to argue someone out of religion. It simply won't happen; you cannot use logic to argue someone out of a point of view where they didn't use logic in the first place to argue themselves into it.

Yes. Only math and logic provide certainty. Unfortunately (sorry, mathematicians!), this is rather uninteresting: Any statement that can be proven to be true given a certain set of axioms is a tautology. E.g. the two sides of the equation (a/b)*(c/d) = (a*c)/(b*d) with real numbers and our usual operations are saying the same thing in different ways; that is exactly what a proof proves.
The only things you can be sure about are trivial.

Yes, because no statement about the world we experience with our senses can be proven. For any data seemingly acquired through observation and any conclusion derived from it you can imagine a scenario in which the conclusion reached from the observation is wrong.
Absolute truth and proofs are exclusive to the world of pure concepts i.e. mathematics.
Some people might argue that mathematics happens within the mind of a human being and is therefore equally fallible. This is based on a confusion: while the human mind can make mistakes, the nature of the mistake is the same as the one a navigator makes when drawing a map of uncharted territory. The territory being explored is not arbitrary, therefore the map can be wrong but not the territory. Indeed, reality is all that is not arbitrary and any explorer will find the same thing in the same place.
All aliens living in all possible universes will discover the exact same mathematics as us. They might have different notation and understanding and focus on different things. But given effort they will discover the monster group, they will discover the Riemann-Zeta function, the incompleteness theorem, and so on. In fact these aliens will most likely have exactly the same arguments we have between different axiomatic sets and which one is "correct". Hint: they all are. The difference is what part of math you choose to explore.

I would offer a frame challenge, in that I believe your question begs the answer.

I like things that I know for sure are true and will remain true.

That right there is quite the tall order.  You may find that you don't like many things.  The topic of "what does it mean to know something" is a very subtle one.  SEP has an entire article on it.  Long story short, it is not uncommon to start from the position that knowledge is Justified (you have a reason behind it) True (it's right) Belief (you believe it).  However, the nuances behind that is so significant that some philosophers argue that the concept of knowledge is beyond analysis.

Are logic and mathematics the only fields where what we say can be proved, and therefore be true without doubts?

The choice of clauses here is interesting.  The first part of the sentence talks of the "justified" element of knowledge, while the latter speaks of "belief."  From the above reading of "knowledge," these are orthogonal, not causal.
To make them causal, we need to make "proved" mean more than justification.  Proved needs to mean justification and it is unreasonable to not believe it.
And therin lies the heart of the frame challenge I offer you: If something has "provability" as a property, is it possible for it to be outside of your definition of logic and mathematics.  I note that mathematics is famously without a concrete definition, so this has to be done with respect to your own personal definition of these terms.
If you can know that any discipline which admits the concept of a "proof" is within logic or mathematics, then you have your answer.
As a re-frame, it may make sense to focus on the concept within logic of deduction.  Deduction and proofs typically go together, so its likely that the topic of deduction will be applicable to what you call proofs.  Something I find interesting in my own journey of seeking knowledge is that so much of the body of mathematics is deductive, and yet the act of being a mathematician is astonishingly inductive/abductive/madness.  That dichotomy may be useful to you for formulating follow-ups.
